# Prove a categorical statement

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

In the answer to [Direct products in subcategories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147713/direct-products-in-subcategories) it is said:

> If $\mathcal{D}$ is a *full* subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ *and* $A \times_{\mathcal{C}} B$ is (isomorphic to) an object of $\mathcal{D}$, then it is isomorphic (in $\mathcal{D}$) to $A \times_{\mathcal{D}} B$. In other words, the embedding of a full subcategory *reflects* products. (In fact, it reflects all limits and colimits.)

How to prove it?

I don't ask for a full detailed proof. A book reference (with a short explanation) would be probably enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subcategory $\mathcal{D}$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is **full** if for all $x,y\in\mathcal{D}$ you have:
$$\hom_\mathcal{D}(x,y)=\hom_\mathcal{C}(x,y)$$
Now products in a category are defined by the usual universal property. Take $x,y\in\mathcal{D}$, then $x\times_\mathcal{C}y$ satisfies the universal property in $\mathcal{D}$ (since $\mathcal{D}$ is a full subcategory). By uniqueness of products, you have that $x\times_\mathcal{C}y \cong x\times_\mathcal{D}y$.

Notice that this is true in general for all limits and colimits in a full subcategory.

Comment: Well...I do not think this answer is very informative/satisfying:  1) $x\times_\mathcal{C}y$ need not be *equal* to $x\times_\mathcal{D}y$ as you wrote, it is only isomorphic in general. I edited it. 2)$x\times_\mathcal{C}y$ need not satisfy the universal property in $\mathcal{D}$ as you state, for the simple reason that it need not exist in $\mathcal{D}$, it is only isomorphic to an object in $\mathcal{D}$. 3)you do not explain why an object in $\mathcal{D}$,  isomorphic to $x\times_\mathcal{C}y$, satisfies the uiversal property in $\mathcal{D}$....

Comment: ... This may be almost obvious to you and to me, but it is exactly what the OP was asking.

Comment: @magma In the question the OP specified that $x\times_\mathcal{C}y$ is isomorphic to an object in $\mathcal{D}$. That's the case in which my answer holds. Obviously, if the product in $\mathcal{C}$ is not (isomorphic to an object) in the subcategory (for example a product of not locally compact CW-complexes is in the category of topological spaces, but not of CW-complexes, if I'm not wrong), then there's a problem.